# The binary you uploaded was invalid. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed

Tags: objective-c

Now I'm sure a lot of you have seen this error message when trying to submit an application in the apple store. And so have I , however I have done everything right just as described on the developers portal. 
Got all the profiles and certificates correct( triple checked) and when I try to build under distribution even here it will not give an error. 
As suggested by the developers portal I checked in my build log for the embedded.mobileprovision and the code sign, and again these are also present !
So my question is what could be the problem here , where will it go wrong ( my icon is also going correct, 57px x 57px and case sensitive name it Icon.png ).
I'm really stuck here. 
I can give some output from my build log maybe someone can get some usefull information from it.

```
Processing "/Users/example/Downloads/Source-3/exampleMobileApp 3/build/Distribution-iphoneos/DrillDownApp.app/Info.plist" Info.plist
cd "/Users/example/Downloads/Source-3/exampleMobileApp 3"
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
<com.apple.tools.info-plist-utility> Info.plist -genpkginfo "/Users/example/Downloads/Source-3/exampleMobileApp 3/build/Distribution-iphoneos/DrillDownApp.app/PkgInfo" -expandbuildsettings -format binary -o "/Users/example/Downloads/Source-3/exampleMobileApp 3/build/Distribution-iphoneos/DrillDownApp.app/Info.plist"

Touch "/Users/example/Downloads/Source-3/exampleMobileApp 3/build/Distribution-iphoneos/DrillDownApp.app"
cd "/Users/example/Downloads/Source-3/exampleMobileApp 3"
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/usr/bin/touch -c "/Users/example/Downloads/Source-3/exampleMobileApp 3/build/Distribution-iphoneos/DrillDownApp.app"

ProcessingProductPackaging /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/Entitlements.plist "/Users/example/Downloads/Source-3/exampleMobileApp 3/build/exampleMobile.build/Distribution-iphoneos/exampleMobile.build/DrillDownApp.xcent"
cd "/Users/example/Downloads/Source-3/exampleMobileApp 3"
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
<com.apple.tools.product-pkg-utility> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/Entitlements.plist -entitlements -format xml -o "/Users/example/Downloads/Source-3/exampleMobileApp 3/build/exampleMobile.build/Distribution-iphoneos/exampleMobile.build/DrillDownApp.xcent"

CodeSign "/Users/example/Downloads/Source-3/exampleMobileApp 3/build/Distribution-iphoneos/DrillDownApp.app"
cd "/Users/example/Downloads/Source-3/exampleMobileApp 3"
setenv CODESIGN_ALLOCATE /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Developer: Paul Braam (R82A3577P5)" "--resource-rules=/Users/example/Downloads/Source-3/exampleMobileApp 3/build/Distribution-iphoneos/DrillDownApp.app/ResourceRules.plist" --entitlements "/Users/example/Downloads/Source-3/exampleMobileApp 3/build/exampleMobile.build/Distribution-iphoneos/exampleMobile.build/DrillDownApp.xcent" "/Users/example/Downloads/Source-3/exampleMobileApp 3/build/Distribution-iphoneos/DrillDownApp.app"
/Users/example/Downloads/Source-3/exampleMobileApp 3/build/Distribution-iphoneos/DrillDownApp.app: replacing invalid existing signature
```

Answer (score 0):

When I get this I try the following (usually in this order) before building again:

1. Restart Xcode
2. Clean all
3. Clean all and delete anything related to the app in the build directory
4. Clean all and delete the whole build directory

The next step would probably be "restart Mac" (and finally "panic") but I've never got that far.